# SQL Sproc Not Populating Field

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently having an issue with a sproc I've created. I'm not "new" to SQL and database logic, but I'm definitely no expert.

First, here's the sproc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `insert_league_data` (
IN partipant_id VARCHAR(45),
IN summoner_id INT, 
IN queue VARCHAR(45),
IN points INT, 
IN tier VARCHAR(10),
IN name VARCHAR(45),
IN division INT
)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO league (
    participant_id, 
    summoner_id, 
    queue,
    points,
    tier,
    name,
    division
    )
VALUES (
    participant_id,
    summoner_id,
    queue,
    points,
    tier,
    name,
    division
    )
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    points=VALUES(points),
    tier=VALUES(tier),
    name=VALUES(name),
    division=VALUES(division);
END
```

The primary key, participant_id, is a VARCHAR(45). I know that using INT is a better paradigm here, but the value is a GUID with a few characters appended to the front. Completely unique.

The problem here is that when I call this sproc (I'm using Python/mysql) the table `league` is only storing one row, with an empty participant_id and the updated values are the values of the last call to the sproc, not actually related to the other information that was stored first.

So does it look like my SQL logic here is flawed? Or might there be another problem, maybe Python related, that I'm missing? I debug through the Python code and the value is being passed into the sproc as expected.

Just in case, here's the Python code:

```
data = (str(league_data.participantId), summoner_id, league_data.queue, 25, league_data.tier, league_data.name, 0)
self.cursor.callproc('insert_league_data', data)
```

**EDIT:** I've done some additional work with it this morning and I found that it is definitely SQL related, not Python; I called the sproc via a SQL query and got the same results.

**EDIT2:** Thanks to @Peter M the solution was in duplicating names for parameters and column names. Is there a good system to use so that the sproc parameters are obvious in what they refer to but don't directly mirror the table's column names?

Comment: Your procedure definition appears to be incomplete.  Where are your parameter definitions?

Comment: @BaconBits I left them out as they seemed unnecessary. I'll add them in though.

Comment: On first glance, having the table column names and parameter names being the same looks suspicious to me.  But I'm not sure.

Comment: @PeterM Yeah you're right! When I first started with SQL on my own outside of work I thought that that might be an issue, but other sprocs I created handled it properly so I just assumed it was no problem. Changed the input for participant_id to p_id and the problem was gone. Is there a good naming convention that I should be following? Something to Google I suppose. Thank you!

Comment: @POB That was just a wild guess on my part, and I'm happy that it solved your issue. But I've never thought about parameter naming conventions before.